# In programming contexts, "a call for a function" or "a call of"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

In programming context, you can call a function. This usage is listed on the dictionary (*"cause the execution of (a subroutine)"* by Oxford), and although I wasn't able to confirm with the dictionaries I have, I'm assuming *call* as a noun can be used in the same manner.

So when I want to rewrite

> By calling this function multiple times, ...

using call as a noun, which preposition do I use?

> By multiple calls *for* this function,

or

> By multiple calls *of* this function,

seems to fit in (to me), and both are found on the internet, as 
[How to limit calls for a function, but to surely process it afterwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887301/how-to-limit-calls-for-a-function-but-to-surely-process-it-afterwards) and [Counting recursive calls of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41203214/counting-recursive-calls-of-a-function).

Which should I choose?

Comment: I would use "calls _to_ this function", but wouldn't find anything odd with "calls _of_ this function". But "calls _for_ this function" doesn't work for me.

Comment: Invoke/Invocation (of) is also very idiomatic, at least in my opinion.

Comment: Both "to" and "of" are quite common.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The most natural way of expressing this would be:

> Your app is making multiple calls to this function.

"Function Foo is making 100 call to Bar when run from Snafu."

> Your app is making multiple calls of this function.

Adds an abstract nature to the sentence.  Sorry, it's difficult to quantify.

> I'm getting multiple call *for* this function.

Implies that people are requesting that a proposed function be written.

Comment: Disagree with the middle one--it's still calls *to* the function.

Comment: "Your app has 100 calls of ToString on an immutable object rather than storing and using the result of one call" - makes sense to me (here, **of** sounds more _right_ than **to**), but it may be most suited to methods **of** objects rather than functions acting **on** objects... Of course, it could all be in my head.

Comment: @JPhil I was thinking almost the exact same thing.  "You making lots of ToString calls."  Or "You app is making calls of ToString variants that maybe it shouldn't."  They sound right but I can't explain why...

Answer (score 14):

I would expect to see **calls *of* this function** or **calls *to* this function**.

Using **calls *for* this function** sounds odd, and partly that may be to do with the fact that "to call for (something)" is a phrase with a very different meaning.

Answer (score 1):

As Dan said, the correct usage is **to** and **of**.

However, say you were making a request to a server. In this situation I'd say you could use **for**.

As in:

> Making multiple calls **to** the server **for** this function.